# Reducing the resolution of population data but getting 1.5x the actual population values

Tags: google-earth-engine, population

I am trying to reduce the resolution of a raster to the resolution of another dataset for later processing. In other words, I would like to reduce the population image by summing the number of people within each pixel of the raster at the the reduced resolution. However, when I double check population size per state to the true population size, I get 1.5x the population size that I should. Does anyone have suggestions for how to update my code so that I can reduce the resolution of the population data properly?

```
//USA states feature collection
var states = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/States")

////define climate var here because will have to change resolution of images below to match
///////// climate vars
// Load the PRISM image collection
var prism_data = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81m')
                  .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2023-03-01');

// Get the projection at required scale
var projectionAt1k = projection.atScale(1000)
print(prismProjection.nominalScale())
var projectionAt4k =  projection.atScale(4638.312116390109) //prism

// Step1: 100 to 1000m
var scaledImage1 = usa_pop
  .reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
    maxPixels: 1024
  })
  // Request the data at the scale and projection
  // of reduced resolution
  .reproject({
    crs: projectionAt1k
  });
// Step2: 1000m to 4000m
var rescaled_pop = scaledImage1
  .reduceResolution({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
    maxPixels: 1024
  })
  // Request the data at the scale and projection
  // of reduced resolution
  .reproject({
    crs: projectionAt4k
  });

// now test that above steps worked by looking at sum per state per year
var rescaled_pop_fc = rescaled_pop.reduceRegions({
  collection: states, 
  tileScale: 16,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()})
```

Comment: Are you resampling to an integer multiple for your cell size? It sounds like you're getting sum of part pixels mixed in with full pixels, that's a common trap, to get around it either use an even multiple of your base cell size or find a way that takes into account the overlap pixel size as a weighted sum.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense! Should I try "weighted" instead of "unweighted"? By even multiple do you mean changing the 4638.312116390109 to 4638?

Comment: An integer multiple for 1000 would be either 4000 or 5000 - 4 whole cells or 5 whole cells. Try it with the weighted option first and review your results, approximately calculate a few cells manually to check the result is logical.